# How to fix the firebase auth?

Tags: flutter

The import package 'package: firebase_auth / firebase_auth.dart'; I get an error, I have already downloaded all the flutter packages with ctrl + shift + p .... get packages.

[image]

Comment: Please only use English language.

Comment: Yes, friend, the description is  in english...

Comment: Show your `pubspec.yaml` file

Answer (score 1):

Add **firebase_auth** to the dependencies in the project's **pubspec.yaml** file.

Since the error in your screenshot says: "Target of URI doesn't exist: 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart'", this is indicative that you have not added firebase_auth to your dependencies in the project's pubspec.yaml file as seen on line 23 of the following screenshot:

[image: paubspec.yaml dependencies]

The indentation of each line in this file is very important, so please make sure they match.

Comment: Thanks jeff, you solved me with
  firebase_auth: ^ 0.8.4 + 2

Comment: Glad I could help, @OswaldoChavarriaV! Please mark my answer as correct if that solved the problem. Thanks!